# RJ45 doubler that allows 2 computers on one plug

Tags: networking, ethernet, adapter

At my work 20 years ago we lacked an RJ45 port. This was solved by plugging in a RJ45-doubler.

It was a passive adapter (so it was neither a switch nor a hub) and looked visually similar to:

[image]

The doubler had the effect that A and B both could reach the internet, but they could not reach each other, and IIRC it also limited the speed to 10 Mbps.

I can find many adapters that merge two RJ45 onto a single cable and then splits these at the other end of the cable with a similar adapter (so you would always buy these in pairs). *This is **not** what I am looking for*.

I am now in a similar situation: I have a router that includes a small switch that is just one port short, but I can easily find 2 cables that will never need to communicate, and where 10 Mbps would be sufficient even if shared and half-duplex (e.g. my printer, my VOIP-adapter, and possibly even my TV-box. None of these would ever communicate directly).

I can find products like [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001804707193.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.416b27b3zPmwXv&algo_pvid=70d788d1-eff4-46ca-9f2b-e5d76f73a21e&algo_expid=70d788d1-eff4-46ca-9f2b-e5d76f73a21e-21&btsid=0bb0624116215909693453015ef7f4&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_) and [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32949687371.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.416b27b3zPmwXv&algo_pvid=70d788d1-eff4-46ca-9f2b-e5d76f73a21e&algo_expid=70d788d1-eff4-46ca-9f2b-e5d76f73a21e-43&btsid=0bb0624116215909693453015ef7f4&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_)
: "This Ethernet splitter allows three computers to share one Ethernet line one at a time, but it doesn't support three computers to connect onto the internet simultaneously."

20 years ago we really *had* multiple (2) computers using the same adapter simultaneously; the only limitation was that these computers could not connect to each other.

What should I search for to find such an adapter?

(Why not buy an additional switch? I want to try to avoid pollution. I have a 24 port old switch, but it uses 18 watts even when there is no traffic, and I would like to turn that off. A new switch might save on the power, but would cause pollution in production.)

Comment: You can get an 8-port ethernet switch for under $£€ 10, which will do the job properly; just daisy-chain it off one of the existing ports.

Comment: @Tetsujin Ahh, but it will need power. I want to avoid both the power usage and the pollution by producing the switch.

Comment: As describes this does not exist in a reliable configuration. The only options I see are:
1. Change the cable every time.   2. Unplug one cable and plug in the other in a duplux switch (effectively no change)  3. Very maybe power down your VIOP, power up the printer and then use it. Preferably using the same power cable (which you would switrch between devices) to make sure not both are active at the same time.  4. Just buy a low power cheap switch and use the 2x2 in pairs (as has multiple answers here).   5. Or why not add a network card to the computer, so it has its own NIC to the printer.

Comment: @Hennes Apart from the limitation described, it was a reliable config at my work. 1-3 would not be a workable solution for me. 4 would increase pollution and the goal is to decrease it. 5 would not work: It is a network printer with multiple clients.

Comment: [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1650766) is the one that correctly identifies the adapter and explains why it won't be useful in your situation. You should buy a switch with more ports than you need, and then donate the switch you have to someone else that needs it. Then you're not adding any new e-waste or buying a product that wouldn't already have been sold.

Comment: Might not like my opinion, but there is an elephant in the room: **you have a TV, a TV box, a VOIP adapter, a printer, and who knows what else - and you try skip acquiring a new (thought about used?) switch - for the reason to save the planet.** Just stop using the TV and you're done. And plant trees in all the free time you now have without Netflix. Environmental consciousness is key to the survival of the planet, but only if done properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called **passive ethernet hub**. The schematic is quite simple, but only works for three devices (two computers and one upstream switch):

[image]
(EEWeb: [Building a Passive Ethernet Hub](https://www.eeweb.com/building-a-passive-ethernet-hub/))

In practice these are quite fiddly even at 10 Mbps, and have been superseded by either powered switches or those pair splitters that you put at both ends and that work up to 100 Mbps.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a 24 port old switch, but it uses 18 watts even when there is no traffic

Newer devices tend to consume less power than older ones.

I measured consumption of my D-Link 8-port Gigabit switch DGS-108. It consumes about 1W with a few devices connected.

With disconnected devices it consumes slightly less.

I also measured similar 5-port version DGS-105, and it consumed only slightly less than DGS-108.

One more thing to think about is opportunity cost (alternative cost). I like the idea to see our time as life currency. If you want you can spend hours choosing most efficient switch or one with least CO2 impact. Or you can spend hours planting trees. Or you can spends hours working more and then donating extra earned money to foundation which for example fights with climate change.

But you can't do all things, because a day has only 24h. Which means that by doing something you won't do something else in the same time.

I don't know which way is best, but I think after some experience you will notice that some ways to help planet may be more effective than others. And you may or may not come to conclusion, that it may be better to choose any switch now and spend this time doing something with more impact.

Answer (score 1):

I have had an encounter with such a setup--although hardwired--some years ago.  (Don't let electricians near a network wire!!)  Despite low loads from the two computers involved it caused noticeable network lag.

Comment: Great. That confirms it can be done. For my use one of the connections will be a network printer, that is rarely in use, so collisions are unlikely to be an issue.

Comment: @OleTange That's assuming all three devices tolerate it.  They aren't expected to be able to.

Answer (score 0):

I have my doubts that the RJ45 doubler you remember was only at one end. I don't see how it could do all these things with no power supply and nothing at the other end. I doubt, but I am not going to say it's impossible, I simply have never seen such a thing for Ethernet, and knowing what I know about Ethernet I can't imagine how it's possible. Anyways, you could go the [hard-switch route](https://www.cableleader.com/catalog/product/view/id/764/s/2-way-rj45-manual-data-switch/). That makes it literal knob you must switch to share the one port. Good luck.

Comment: I am 100% sure it was one end. Why? Because during debugging (where we found out we could not access each other) we took it out and plugged in an ethernet cable directly.

Comment: Yeah. My bad. You were right.

Answer (score 0):

These can work by exploiting the fact that the cable has eight wires and only four are needed.  So within the cable it splits onto the unused pairs.  But they are double ended.

You say you are 100% sure that it was single ended.  But in an answer you give your reason for being sure was that you replaced it with a normal ethernet cable.  That is not proof it was single ended, because that would have used the default four wires, which are one of the two sets of four connected at the server end.

And of course that applies pre Cat 6 cable.  Cat 6 uses all 8 wires anyway.

Comment: "Cat 6" doesn't change how many wires are used, "Gigabit Ethernet" does. You can run 1GBASE-T over Cat5 and it'll use 8 wires; you can run 100BASE-T over Cat6 or Cat7 and it'll still use only 4 wires.